# Coverage Reports with Instanbul JS, Vue JS, Vue CLI, Cypress e2e tests, and Typescript only showing a few files

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, cypress, istanbul

I'm running a VueJS app written in Typescript and am testing it with Cypress e2e tests. I'd like to get coverage reports setup to see how much of my code I've covered with the tests so I attempted to integrate Istanbul JS. The documentation from Istanbul JS and Cypress makes this look totally doable, but nothing is ever as easy as it seems. Note the **output** below which only has 3 files reported on despite the fact that this app has hundreds of files and base Vue files like `main.ts` and `router.ts` are not even included. Where are the rest of the files and how do I get a full coverage report of my Vue app?

I have my project setup per the Cypress [code coverage documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage.html#Full-stack-code-coverage) with the following files:

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [
            '@vue/app',
            {
                useBuiltIns: 'entry',
            },
        ],
    ],
    plugins: [ 'istanbul' ],
}
```

**nyc.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    extends: '@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript',
    all: true,
    extension: [
        '.vue',
        '.ts',
    ],
    include: [
        'src/**/*.{vue,ts}',
    ],
}
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "e2e": "NODE_ENV=production vue-cli-service test:e2e --mode 'e2e'",
    "coverage": "npm run e2e -- --headless --spec tests/e2e/specs/example.test.js && npx nyc report --reporter=text"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@cypress/code-coverage": "1.10.1",
    "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript": "0.1.3",
    "@types/chai": "4.2.4",
    "@types/chart.js": "2.8.10",
    "@types/gtag.js": "0.0.3",
    "@types/mocha": "5.2.7",
    "@types/parse": "2.2.15",
    "@types/ramda": "0.26.33",
    "@types/stripe-v3": "3.1.9",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "4.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "4.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "4.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "4.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": "4.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-service": "4.0.5",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "4.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.3",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "5.2.0",
    "chai": "4.2.0",
    "cypress": "3.6.0",
    "eslint": "6.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "5.2.3",
    "node-sass": "4.13.0",
    "nyc": "14.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "8.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "0.5.16",
    "stylelint": "11.1.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "19.0.0",
    "ts-node": "8.4.1",
    "typescript": "3.6.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.10",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.6.0"
}
```

**Cypress plugins/index.js**

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('task', require('@cypress/code-coverage/task'))

    return Object.assign({}, config, {
        integrationFolder: 'tests/e2e/specs',
        screenshotsFolder: 'tests/e2e/screenshots',
        videosFolder: 'tests/e2e/videos',
        supportFile: 'tests/e2e/support/index.js',
    })
}
```

**Cypress support/index.js**

```
import '@cypress/code-coverage/support'
import './commands'

Cypress.Screenshot.defaults({
    screenshotOnRunFailure: false,
})
```

```
------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                          |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files                     |    20.24 |        0 |     4.44 |    19.87 |                   |
 Charts                       |    54.55 |        0 |        0 |       50 |                   |
  ScoreSummaryChart.vue       |    54.55 |        0 |        0 |       50 |    40,48,54,62,79 |
 Quizzes                      |    15.93 |        0 |        0 |    16.19 |                   |
  QuizView.vue                |    15.93 |        0 |        0 |    16.19 |... 13,416,417,418 |
 Tiles                        |    22.73 |        0 |    15.38 |    21.95 |                   |
  QuizOverviewTile.vue        |    22.73 |        0 |    15.38 |    21.95 |... 71,175,185,188 |
------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Comment: Are you using **@cypress/code-coverage**, shown in this section [E2E code coverage](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage.html#E2E-code-coverage). I found it quite good, if you look under the hood it automatically adds `afterEach()` and `after()` to your tests to aggregate the results. You would need to enable in support and plugins, which is not mentioned above. The only down-side to it is it gives too much coverage when you want to focus on one feature (say your Quizzes feature).

Comment: Yeah I have that and all the other packages that were recommended in those docs. I just updated the question with all of my `devDependencies` if you want to take a look.

Comment: K I've added the code from my plugins and support index files to the question. I've watched the headed e2e tests run and do see the Istanbul coverage scripts running as described in the Cypress docs on coverage setup (though it is only for the 3 files in the report). I've also explored the contents of `/.nyc_output/out.json` and it has the data from those 3 .vue files but nothing else. I am explicitly calling `nyc` in the script that runs _after_ the e2e scripts run because I want to generate an html report, but that has nothing to do with the actual generation of the test data.

Comment: So effectively you run nyc twice - once within the code coverage package and again in the script. Ideally you want to configure the reporter in nyc config and let the package handle running nyc. Default reporters are ['lcov', 'clover', 'json']. It also says in package that custom nyc options are pulled from nyc section in package.json, so that's where to set text reporter.

Comment: But you are correct the nyc run is not the crux of the problem. I also have **@cypress/webpack-preprocessor** in my setup. In plugins/index.js `const webpack = require('@cypress/webpack-preprocessor')` and `module.exports = (on, config) => { on('file:preprocessor', webpack(options))...`.

Comment: Yeah that's fair. I could just add those reporters to my config file. Regarding the preprocessor, I thought that was just for combining unit and e2e test coverage reports?

Comment: I also went ahead and tried adding the `file:preprocessor` (though I required `@cypress/code-coverage/use-babelrc` instead of including `webpack-preprocessor` because I'm not using webpack) to my `plugins/index.js` file  and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: 'Not using webpack' - most coverage examples are based on webpack, so this may be hard to solve. BTW standard vue-cli has webpack under the hood, so maybe you are actually using it. If so, **babel-loader** may be required.

Comment: Yeah sorry I should have clarified. I'm definitely using Webpack under Vue-CLIs hood, but I am not using it directly. Do you have an example of how I would use **babel-loader**? I haven't seen that in any documentation, but am definitely willing to try!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. add `@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript` to your devDependencies
2. babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'],
  plugins: [
    ['babel-plugin-istanbul', {
      extends: '@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript',
      extension: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.vue']
    }]
  ]
}
```

3. delete the `nyc.config.js` file
4. delete `node_modules/.cache`
5. restart your server